# OpenCL Sample Program issue on Nvidia GEForce

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I am new to OpenCL and trying to run a sample code from one of tutorials for matrix vector multiplication. There are two files, one is matvec.c which launches the kernel and the second matvec.cl which holds the kernel function.
The program is as follows:

```
#define PROGRAM_FILE "matvec.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "matvec_mult"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
int main() {
cl_platform_id platform;
cl_device_id device;
cl_context context;
cl_command_queue queue;
cl_int i, err;
cl_program program;
FILE *program_handle;
char *program_buffer, *program_log;
size_t program_size, log_size;
cl_kernel kernel;
size_t work_units_per_kernel;
float mat[16], vec[4], result[4];
float correct[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
cl_mem mat_buff, vec_buff, res_buff;
for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
mat[i] = i * 2.0f;
            }
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
vec[i] = i * 3.0f;
    correct[0] += mat[i] * vec[i];
    correct[1] += mat[i+4] * vec[i];
    correct[2] += mat[i+8] * vec[i];
    correct[3] += mat[i+12] * vec[i];
}
clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1,
&device, NULL);
context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL,
NULL, &err);
program_handle = fopen(PROGRAM_FILE, "r");
fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
program_size = ftell(program_handle);
rewind(program_handle);
program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size,
program_handle);
fclose(program_handle);
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
(const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
free(program_buffer);
clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &err);
mat_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*16, mat, &err);
vec_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*4, vec, &err);
res_buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
sizeof(float)*4, NULL, &err);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mat_buff);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &vec_buff);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &res_buff);
work_units_per_kernel = 4;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
&work_units_per_kernel, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, res_buff, CL_TRUE, 0,
sizeof(float)*4, result, 0, NULL, NULL);
if((result[0] == correct[0]) && (result[1] == correct[1])
&& (result[2] == correct[2]) && (result[3] == correct[3])) {
printf("Matrix-vector multiplication successful.\n");
}
else {
printf("Matrix-vector multiplication unsuccessful.\n");
}
clReleaseMemObject(mat_buff);
clReleaseMemObject(vec_buff);
clReleaseMemObject(res_buff);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseContext(context);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The Kernel function is as follows:

```
#include <CL\cl.h>

__kernel void matvec_mult(__global float4* matrix, __global float4* vector,__global   
float* result) {                       
int i = get_global_id(0);
result[i] = dot(matrix[i], vector[0]);
}
```

When I run this sample code, it displays "Matrix-vector multiplication unsuccessful". I am using Visual Studio 2010 and tried to debug the code. The values of the correct variable which is generated by a simple 'for loop' does not match the result variable which is generated by the kernel function. Can somebody help me with this issue & point out where I am going wrong, I am not able to confirm whether it is the code issue or the system issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

One of the errors: "IntelliSense: identifier "get_global_id" is undefined".

Comment: You are not checking the error codes from any of the OpenCL API function calls. Any one of these functions could be returning an error - it's impossible for us to guess which one it is. Please add some error checks to your code, re-run the program, and then let us know which function is failing (and what error code it reports).

Comment: @Jprice, I have tried to check any error mentioned by the compiler. There is no particular error in the matvec.c, however, I receive undefined intellisense errors for the kernel function in the matvec.cl. It says, __kernel undefined, __global undefined, matrix, vector, dot & get_global_id is also undefined. But it compiles okay even with these errors. I am unable to trace the exact reason for this issue. Also, while debugging it just gives me the address of the kernels and I do not have much experience debugging OpenCL code in Visual Studio.

Comment: OpenCL API functions return code or set code value, like this one: clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err) or this: err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mat_buff). Check err value every time, it must be CL_SUCCESS.

Comment: @Roman, thanks for your reply. I have checked the code as per your instructions. All API function calls generate a value of "0".  The only function call which does not generate a "0" is 
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
It generates "-45". Can you help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error codes are defined in `<CL/cl.h>`

Error -45 is CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE. According to [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateKernel.html) it means that "there is no successfully built executable for program". There is unnecessary inclusion at first raw of your kernel source. Delete it:

```
#include <CL\cl.h>
```

OpenCL C doesn't allow to include regular C/C++ headers. Only OpenCL C-compliant source files can be included.

Generally, in order to see, what errors OpenCL compiler produces, when building kernel, include source code like this: *(I took snippet from existing code, so check variable names, etc.)*

```
cl_int ret;

program = clCreateProgramWithSource(
    context, 1, (const char**)&src_file, NULL, &ret);

if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error with code %d happened.\n", ret);
}

// Warnings will be treated like errors, this is useful for debug
char build_params[] = {"-Werror"};    
ret = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, build_params, NULL, NULL);

if (ret != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char *buffer;

    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,
        device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);

    buffer = calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,
        device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);

    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, your code was able to pointout the issue. Here is the error: front end compiler build failed. Do you have any suggestion for this issue.

Comment: This means that OpenCL compiler front-end is unable to process OpenCL C code into intermediate representation. Usually that is caused by syntactic errors. Did you remove header inclusion in your kernel file?

Comment: thanks again. I do not have any header inclusion in my matvec.cl file. I have already removed the "#include <CL\cl.h>". It justs this code __kernel void matvec_mult(__global float4* matrix, __global float4* vector,__global   
float* result) {                       
int i = get_global_id(0);
result[i] = dot(matrix[i], vector[0]);
}

Comment: I tested your code on my PC, and it's just fine (though, I have Radeon GPU). Check your OpenCL SDK & project settings, it looks like your problem isn't related to code itself.

Comment: I currently have Nvidia GEFORCE  as well as Intel inbuilt graphics. Now, I checked the platform ID on this code & it displays Intel(R)Corporation. Is there anyway possible to change the platform for running OpenCL in my system to Nvidia. Please let me know your suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: Look at code, located at https://github.com/RomanArzumanyan/SCOW. You need files platforms.h and platforms.c. Functions inside are exactly what you need.

Comment: thank you for the link. I will check the link and get back to you.